# Perl и настройка скриптов cgi

Tags: cgi, настройка, perl

Рыскал в интернете, как настроить скрипт cgi. Нашел только то, что нужно изменять `CHMOD`. Но где и как, найти не удалось... вот я учусь в школе, где есть терминальный класс с компами.
У нас есть страница на сайте школы, где мы можем тестировать свои скрипты. Эта операция с настройками делается на сервере? Это первый вопрос. И если нет, то как это сделать в терминальном классе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> эта операция с настройками делается на сервере?

Да, скрипты находятся на сервере и там же задаются права доступа (chmod\chown)

> и если нет то как это сделать в терминальном классе?

В классе windows или Linux? В первом варианте, вообще ничего делать не надо. Во втором также поменять chmod\chown на такие как принято в настройках вашего web сервера.

Comment: Там linux. Хотя вот там на компьютере есть папка cgi-bin, куда мы закидываем скрипты. А где нужно менять параметры chmod/chown?

Comment: Хотя вот там на компьютере - это на сервере? Тогда надо подключиться туда с помощью ssh и выставить права. Не удивлюсь, что это все сделано у вас автоматически\\прозрачно т.е. от вас требуется лишь положить скрипт в папку cgi-bin. Или он не работает таким образом? Какая ошибка? 500 Internal Server Error ? ))

Comment: не работает таким образом....ошибка 500ая

Comment: 1. проверить отстутвие ошибок в файле
    perl -c имяфайла.cgi
2. если ошибок нет, убедиться, что посылаются правильные заголовки т.е. перед первым выводом (print), должны быть правильные заголовки (print "Content-type: text/html\n\n")
3. Убедиться, что используются те модули (use ...), что есть на сервере
4. если первые три пункта выполнены, то тогда нада просто спросить у местного админа\\преподавателя

p.s. дописать в начало use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); чтобы видеть ошибки в браузере

Comment: спасибо...за внимание....постараюсь все сделать как надо.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Положите скрипт в папку `cgi-bin` или какая там у вас папка для cgi-скриптов.
2. chmod a+x имя_файла
3. perl -c имя_файла, если вылезут ошибки - поправьте код
4. Пробуйте через браузер

Еще у браузера есть лог, в который будут сыпаться ошибки. Будучи на сервере по ssh, поищите в конфиге апача (httpd.conf) "ErrorLog", неподалеку будет имя файла лога. Или спросите админа сервера, где лежит error log апача. Он должен понять.

Посмотрите, что пишут там в момент вызова скрипта через браузер.

Comment: Всееем спасибо получилось...